# Unwanted left-padding added in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My webpage menu placement changed a bit in Tablet/Mobile view when I created a WP Theme of my HTML/CSS.

WP added a left-padding to the menu and I don't know how to get rid of it.

HTML/CSS: http://tigu.hk.tlu.ee/~jaan.koppe/veebiprogrammeerimine/portfolio/

WP: http://jaankoppe.planet.ee/wp4

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the default `padding` added to the `ul` in `<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">` overwrite or change that css to `padding: 0;`. Also all of your menu items are set to `float: left` and it's not needed (at least in mobile/tablet view). I would remove the floats

Comment: I added a padding:0 to #menu ul and it worked, thanks!

I also tried to remove the floats ( they apply to all devices ), but then the design broke down.